# Remove Store name in URL

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

I setup store theme with demo.
It setup 5 stores with different homepage.

now my URI is including store name, which I dont need
my store URI should be 'xyz.com/'

How I can remove this `/english1`

[image]

**Store**

[image]

**Edit**
Also How can I remove all these Languages

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the configuration,

```
Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Url Option -> Add Store Code to Urls -> NO
```

To remove Languages,

/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: really appreciate Thanks :)

Comment: is this working correctly for all domains.?

Comment: Actually I need only 1 store, will delete all other stores. You suggestion solve my issue.

Comment: ok you are welcome..

Comment: do you know how we can remove language as well? I dont need these langauges, Check updated question.

Comment: I have updated the answer ..